# Print string from arduino to serial monitor

Tags: serial, string

I want to send text over serial monitor to Arduino and make Arduino return that string back to me over serial monitor.

I have made this function which reads from serial input and returns a string object.

```
String readSerial() {
    String input;
    while(Serial.available() > 0)
        input.concat(Serial.read());
    return input;
}
```

In the `loop()` I have:

```
if(Serial.available()) Serial.print(readSerial());
```

If I just do something like `Serial.print("Hello world!");` everything is fine. But, if I try to return string object I get lot's of numbers.

I guess `Serial.print` doesn't know how to read `String` object and returns ASCII codes of characters or something?

**[update]**
I have checked it, and it's indeed outputing ASCII codes. For `Hi` I get `72105`.

**[update]**
I have updated my `readSerial` function to use this :

```
input += (char)Serial.read();
```

But now I'm getting carriage return and new line after every character:

```
[SEND] Hi
H(CR)
i(CR)
```

So, how can I make it return my text so that is readable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String.concat()` takes a `String` as the second argument. `Serial.read()` returns an `int`. The compiler creates code that converts the `int` into a `String` similar to this:

```
input.concat(String(Serial.read()));
```

This is not what you want.

Let's tell the compiler what you really want instead:

```
input.concat((char)Serial.read());
```

This will tell the compiler to do the following:

```
input.concat(String((char)Serial.read()));
```

We are now having the compiler call the correct `String` constructor, and the code will work as we expect.

Comment: Yes, just figured that out. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Answering the other part of the question:

- you're getting CRs because your readString is just wrong.

The problem is that you don't wait for receiving a whole line of string. For example, if you press H on the serial monitor, then it is getting received and echoed back as if it would been the whole input, ending with a new line.

You might wish to check my answer at [Get strings from Serial.read()](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/22474/get-strings-from-serial-read/22475#22475) that is use https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/ReadStringUntil which reads you the whole string until a separator (for example the whole string until it ends with a CR when you press Enter on the serial monitor).