# Get strings from Serial.read()

Tags: serial, string

I want to read strings from `Serial.read()` to send them later.

To get the data from the Serial monitor I'm doing this:

```c
String stringOne  = "";
int  incomingByte; 

if (Serial.available() > 0) {   

  while(Serial.available() > 0)
  {
     incomingByte= Serial.read();
     stringOne = String(stringOne + String(incomingByte));
  }

  Serial.println(stringOne);
  stringOne = "";
```

The issue is that when I type:

```
'a'
```

I got:

```
'97'
```

for 
    'abc'

I got

```
'979899'
```

so on and so forth.

What should I do in order to get the same string I type?

Comment: Read this: https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/01/reading-serial-on-the-arduino/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're adding the ASCII value of each char to your string, hence you get numbers. See the various String constructors at:
https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StringConstructors

Either cast the read byte to a char:

```
stringOne = String(stringOne + String((char)incomingByte));
```

or consider receiving characters as chars, instead of ints:

```
char incomingByte;
```

There is a perfectly valid one-method call which does all of this hassle easier and more efficiently: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/ReadStringUntil

Note that you'll sooner or later anyhow have to add a framing prototcol. For example, you're sending down text commands to Arduino, and each command is separated by a new line character. ReadStringUntil will handle that very nicely.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using:

```
while(Serial.available() > 0)
  {
     incomingByte= Serial.read();
     stringOne = String(stringOne + String(incomingByte));
  }
```

Use the following to cast them to character:

```
while(Serial.available() > 0)
  {
     char incomingByte= Serial.read();
     stringOne.concat(incomingByte));
  }
Serial.println(stringOne);
stringOne="";
```